# Postgres column not found error (node-postgres)

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I was querying my database to update a value, however, I keep running into this error from nodejs. When I do it from the command line, the query works, but from the javascript code it fails the same way, column "value" does not exist.

```
client.query("UPDATE chore_list SET " + req.body.choseday.toLowerCase() + "=" +  req.user.email  + " WHERE chore ='" + req.params.chorename + "'")
```

In the terminal, I put single quotes around the last parameter and it works, however, in the nodejs code above, the error appears regardless.

error: column "test" does not exist

Comment: What is the actual statement you expect to be sending? Are you certain that that your inputs are actually what you expect them to be? Notably you are getting values from both `req.body` and `req.params`, so I would suggest logging those values to inspect them. Even consider constructing the statement string ( It's just a string afterall ) outside of the `query()` method and logging that produced value as well, in order to see that it also is constructed identically to the statement you expect and are certain that works without the same error.

Comment: I logged the values and they definitely exist. In fact the final parameter is not a column but rather a value in a column I am looking for. It seems to be an issue with the single quotes since I have to put single quotes around the value in the terminal, but those don’t seem to be recognized here.

Comment: Then swap the quotes. i.e `" WHERE chore ='" + req.params.chorename + "'"` becomes `' WHERE chore = "'+ req.params.chorename + '"'`. Also note when asking a question, things like "I actually typed the quotes differently" are really vital pieces of information which people can recognize as an actual problem right away. When you actually tell them that is,

Comment: SQL uses ```'``` (single quotes) for strings. Thus changing the quotes should make it even worse. I guess your problem here are missing quotes instead..

Comment: Don't build queries like that use [parameterized queries](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries) instead. When building queries manually you need to properly escape all symbols and values you put in the query because otherwise you will run into errors with certain values and worse you are open to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (note the additional quotes around the assigned value):

```js
let userEmail = req.user.email.replace(/'/g, "''");
client.query(
    "UPDATE chore_list
        SET " + req.body.choseday.toLowerCase() + " = '" +  userEmail  + "'
        WHERE chore ='" + req.params.chorename + "'"
);
```

**EDIT**: I also added the replace of single quotes (by 2 single quotes) to prevent your (perhaps) unsafe value from interrupting the SQL string.

Comment: Putting quotes around values is not enough you also need to properly escape special characters in the contents of those variables.

Comment: Yes that is correct, ne more argument for parameterized queries. Eventhough I don't know how they behave with dynamic column names (but perhaps the needed value here might to be assumed as "save" and can stay as part of the builded string; I have no experience with them directly). But to assure properly quoting you just need to double all single quotes in Postgres, since backslashes are only interpreted if you put an ```E``` in front of the string. I add this to the answer

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found a workaround for the dynamic column names by using and IF ELSE statement in the JavaScript portion of my code. This way I could just use the parameterized version supported by node pg, and got it to work.